# How do I create a window that uses both .pack() and .grid()?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
def __init__(self):
    self.root = Tk()

    self.title = Frame(self.root, width = 500, height = 35)
    self.title.pack(side = TOP, expand = True)

    self.frame = Frame(self.root, width = 574, height = 574)
    self.frame.grid(columnspan = 30, rowspan = 31)

    self.label = Label(self.title, width = 300, height = 30)
    self.label.pack()

    self.root.mainloop()
```

I want to be able to have a label on top of the grid but when I run the mainloop i get the error: "cannot use geometry manager grid inside .55652592 which already has slaves managed by pack." Thank you.

Comment: What layout is it exactly you're after? If you want a label to appear on top of a grid you can use `place`. Otherwise put the gridded widgets inside a frame which can be packed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to use both. I recommend using `.grid()` consistently because it has a wider range of options. Both `.grid()` and `.pack()` are window managers, and you can't have two window managers running at the same time (at least for the same program).

Instead of using a `label`, you might want to look into `tkMessageBox`, or designating a space for your labels to go (with `grid`, you can have one label replace the other).

This resource might be helpful:

http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm

It advises to never mix the two managers in the same master window.

Best of luck, and happy coding!